# Log plot of residual error for numerical solution of ODE

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

Below I am giving the code that I am using

```
lowsol = NDSolve[{y'[x] == 1/(2 y[x]), y[0] == 1/10}, y, {x, 0, 1}, 
   InterpolationOrder -> All];

residual[x_] = y'[x] - 1/(2 y[x]);

Plot[Evaluate[RealExponent[{residual[x] /. lowsol}]], {x, 0, 1}, 
 PlotStyle -> {GrayLevel[0]}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

I want log plot, thanks!!!

Comment: `I want log plot` but values are all negative. May be try `LogPlot[Abs@Evaluate[RealExponent[{residual[x] /. lowsol}]], {x, 0, 
  1}]`

Comment: Dear Nasser,  I want the plot y-axes like 10^-5, 10^--10..

Comment: The errors should be small tend to zero

Comment: `LogPlot[Evaluate[10^RealExponent[{residual[x] /. lowsol}]], {x, 0, 1},
  PlotStyle -> {GrayLevel[0]}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]`? @Nasser may have meant `LogPlot[Evaluate[Abs[{residual[x] /. lowsol}]], {x, 0, 1}, 
 PlotStyle -> {GrayLevel[0]}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]`

Comment: Many thanks Nasser and Michael both comments are very useful...

Comment: Can we replace runge-kutta 4 method instead of NDSolve?..thanks